# jQuery slider affecting WordPress menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, slider

I was wondering if someone can help me out with this issue.
I have downloaded the [NivoGallery](http://nivogallery.dev7studios.com/) and add it to a WP theme that I am building with [Thematic Framework](http://themeshaper.com/thematic/), but I have one small issue that I can't fix.
As the title says, the jQuery added on the slider is disabling the JS of the standard WP-Thematic menu.
The code below is included with a function into the theme.

```
    <div id="gallery" class="nivoGallery">
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); 
?>/admin/js/jquery.nivo.gallery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#gallery').nivoGallery();
    });
</script>`
```

It mostly seems like the issue is caused by

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

I have tried with jQuery noConflict, but does not seem to work, it breaks.
Let me know if you need the entire html code and jquery.nivo.gallery.js file.

I have found this solution: 
        function add_js_for_slider() {
            ?>
                
                /admin/js/jquery.nivo.gallery.js">
                
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#gallery_slider').nivoGallery();
                });

Is possible to get rid of the jquery line, and still keep it working? Even if WP has jquery, if I remove that line from my function the slider breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery is already included in wordpress, therefore you don't need to include it from googleapis.

nivo gallery can handle jQuery noConflict. If you try that u just need to change $ to jQuery in your code.

Comment: I've found a solution, but I still had to include jquery, it does not work otherwise.  I had to create another function and to add add_action('init', 'add_js_for_slider');